# Objc save a file to the tmp/ with URL it is not working

Tags: objective-c, url, response

if i do the following it works fine

```
NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
```

But if i try to save it using the URL (although it returns the correct path) it does not save it.

```
NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[response URL] absoluteString]];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a system file path don't use

```
[[response URL] absoluteString]
```

because the string starts with the scheme `file://`

use

```
[[response URL] path]
```

instead, which starts with the `/`

But I doubt that appending the full path to the temporary directory is what you want.

Comment: thank you for the fast reply. you are right i am trying to save 2 files in the tmp directory and because [response suggestedFilename] is the same one overrides the other so i need a better way to do this and i thought with the URL this could be achieved. I will try it with the path but i doubt i can create directories there.